# Getting an SCNNode's bounding volume with rotation

Tags: swift, geometry, scenekit

I have a very simple scene set up using the XCode level editor.

[image]

As you can see, one of the 1x5 rectangular cuboids has been rotated by 90º. This was achieved by setting the y attribute of the Euler Angles property to 90 in the Node Inspector.

[image]

But notice that the Bounding Box doesn't account for the cuboids rotation. This is also the case when I iterate through the SCNNodes in the scene. Both cuboids have the same Bounding Volumne

```
for wall:SCNNode in walls.childNodes {
    var v1 = SCNVector3Zero
    var v2 = SCNVector3Zero
    wall.getBoundingBoxMin(&v1, max:&v2)
    print(v1, v2)
}

// Prints
// SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: 0.0, z: -2.5) SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 2.5)
// SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: 0.0, z: -2.5) SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 2.5)
```

So it seems the Bounding Volume is calculated using the child node's own coordinate system, not node parent's (or scene's) coordinate system. Which leaves me wondering; How do I calculate the SCNNodes bounding volume in the scene?

Looking through the documentation for SCNNode, it seems all the information is there. I can read the `eulerAngles` which gives me the correct rotation around the y axis. I can read the `transform` property.

I thought I might be able to multiply the vectors by the nodes transform matrix, but the transform matrix (4x4) and bounding box vectors (1x3) don't appear to be compatible. Nor does SceneKit appear to provide any methods for applying a transformation matrix to a vector. However, I'm not great with Geometry so I could be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. In Interface Builder, as shown on your screenshot, there's an *Editing space* property that you can set to *World* (instead of *Local*)
2. In code, you can use a temporary node to compute the bounding box. Make sure that only has one child node (the node whose bounding box you want to compute), apply any transform on that child node, and they ask the *parent node* for its bounding box. From the documentation:

> The bounding volume of a node containing child nodes is the minimal volume that encloses the bounding volumes of the node’s children.

3. Get the node's bounding box and then use utils such as `-convertPosition:toNode:` to compute the bounding box in another's coordinate system

Comment: Thanks. Point 1 - I don't have to option to adjust the rotation when in 'World' mode. I don't think point 3 is valid. It doesn't account for rotation. I went with a variation of number 2 - All of my Wall Nodes are children of a Walls (plural) node. So I iterate through all the children, setting their hidden property to true. Then I iterate the children again, but this time setting hidden to false, getting the boundingBox for the wallsNode, then setting the hidden property to true again. Once I've done everything I need to do, I set hidden to false on all the wall nodes again.

Comment: Is this really the smartest way to do this? It seems like knowing a nodes bounding volume would be a pretty common occurrence. And this feels like a very clumsy, unintuitive way to accomplish that.

Comment: Point 3 should work too. You'll have to convert the 8 positions (each corner of the bounding box), and then find the minimum and maximum value along each axis in the new coordinate space.

Comment: Basically you can just use -convertVector:toNode: for min/max values of node's bounding box.